# What is a line length "soft limit" and how do I interpret this in the PSR-2 convention?

Tags: php, coding-style, conventions

I don't understand this part of php's [PSR-2](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-2-coding-style-guide.md) convention:

> The soft limit on line length MUST be 120 characters; automated style checkers **MUST** warn but **MUST NOT** error at the soft limit.
>
> Lines **SHOULD NOT** be longer than 80 characters; lines longer than that **SHOULD** be split into multiple subsequent lines of no more than 80 characters each.

I thought "soft limit" meant *"try to stick to this limit, but a few characters extra are not a problem"*. But then I read the second line and now I don't get it.

Comment: See the description of `MUST`, `MUST NOT` and `SHOULD` at the top of the document (see also: [RFC 2119](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2119.txt)).

Comment: Ignore the line length parts they're crap and pointless and often splitting lines especially mid functions/regex etc does nothing but make it even harder to read.  My main bugbears with the rules are the 2 lines about the {} positioning. I hate hate hate it when people put it on a different line rather than on the same line as the function or method declaration line etc you end up with stray { all over the place and it becomes a nightmate to trace them. not to mention the extra added whitespace creates excessive file bloat

Comment: Also see the description of `MUST`, `MUST NOT`, and `SHOULD` in the English language.

Comment: @igorw My interpretation is something like this, and does not make much sense to me: "Lines should be 80 characters max, but you can surpass that limit if you have to. But then again there is another limit at 120, which you MUST not surpass, but you can if you have to (because you MUST respect it, but it's a soft limit)."

Comment: The two lines are not mutually exclusive, inasmuch as the second uses "SHOULD" and the first uses "MUST".

Comment: @GarethL But the first is soft

Comment: @Dave I really feel you Dave, but maybe having an annoying convention is better than not having one at all.

Comment: I have rephrased those two lines for you: There is **no** hard limit on line length specified in PSR-2. There is a general recommendation to keep lines shorter than 80 characters, and a soft limit of 120 characters which automated style checkers must warn you about.

Answer (score 63):

It's pretty easy:

- 0-80: Always ok
- 80-120: Acceptable (if there's a good reason for it, e.g. a string where wrapping it would be ugly)
- 120+: Lint tools, IDEs, etc. MUST show a warning (but never an error!) since the line might be ugly/unreadable/...

Comment: So ... in short it does not make *any* sense to use the wording "soft wrap" because it has to be defined what soft wrap even means right beside the usage? Because no answer in here does really explain what soft wrap means (soft wrap: IDE = warning, hardwrap: IDE = linebreak on code format?)

Answer (score 9):

There is no **hard limit** in PSR-2.

The **MUST (NOT)** refers to automated style checkers, not to you as a programmer.

Also note the section that says that `no error` should be issued when exceeding the soft limit.

Answer (score 4):

### Let me add something to the above answers

#### Editor setup

I was reading the fig standards as well, and I've stumbled against the same question.

After giving a deeper look to my IDE settings (PhpStorm), I've found a little note underneath the general "Code style" page, you wouldn't see that note in the php code section.

**The note reports:**

> "Specify one guide (80) or several (80, 120)"

**That allowed a better interpretation of the PSR rules, which I'm now reading like this:**

> "You shouldn't write lines longer than **80** characters, but you can
>   if you need to. If you exceed the 80 characters, in any case avoid
>   lines longer than **120** characters".

That is totally possibile if you have two vertical rulers: set them to **80, 120** and you will know when the first limit is exceeded (warning), and also when you have passed the second one (halt!).

If you use automatic code formatting (I do, and people *hates me*), then you can set into the php code style page the **Hard wrap at: 120**. This setting will ensure that the PSR rule if followed.

#### Personal toughts

To be honest, nowadays we have monitors that are a lot ***WIDER*** than the old ones, because they use the 16:9 aspect ratio instead of 4:3. So I don't see that urgency to follow the 120 characters rule, because a 16:9 monitor can easily handle more than 200 characters on a line (I've printed 224 on my screen).

Anyway, *I don't like the idea of breaking the rules*, if I can, I try to follow them when speaking about coding standards. 
Maybe I don't see the point of a rule, but if there's a whole team who discussed about that topic, and decided to set the limit at 120 characters, then maybe there's a reason behind that decision that I cannot see, so I just adhere to it. That's the point of a Standard for me.

#### Why 120 is a good compromise

In fact, in the last weeks I've started to split vertically my editor's window, keeping some file types on the left, while some other types (usally JavaScript) on the right. That can be a bit weird at the beginning, I'm the kind of person very disturbed from misaligned stuff. But now I've got used to it, because in practice, it works better like that!

I've read somewhere that our sight doesn't keep up very well with lines longer than a certain amount, and you can easily understand why. Try to read a document with lines longer than 200, you will loose the focus a lot more easily. Probably you will loose the point a lot of times and read again the whole line...if you can find where it starts!

Instead a document long between 80 and 120 maxiumum, will have more lines, but will be much more readable, and you can also split the screen horizontally, without having to scroll, most of the time.

I just wanted to say what I discovered on PhpStorm, and as usual *I ended up writing a papyrus.* **I apologize :)**

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that I've seen another explanation somewhere… I don't know if it's true, but I feel like I should share it =)

Ok, here it goes: no line should be longer than 80, *but that does not account for the indentation*. With the indentation, the limit is 120.

So, if your current indentation is 80 (consider "guards", btw…) — you have only 40 characters remaining. But it your current indention is 40 or less — you can use up to 80 chars for the actual code.

Answer (score 0):

The key to understand *all* FIG standards is to properly interprate [key words used in RFCs](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2119).

> There **MUST NOT** be a hard limit on line length.

Although no one will put a gun to your head…

> The soft limit on line length **MUST** be 120 characters.

… it would be better not exceed the length of 120 characters…

> Lines **SHOULD NOT** be longer than 80 characters; lines longer than that SHOULD be split into multiple subsequent lines of no more than 80 characters each.

… but, as a recommendation, try to split lines longer than 80 characters.

---

It all comes down to readability. Legibility research specific to digital text has shown that, like with printed text, line length can affect reading speed ([saccade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saccade)). Also, it turns out that the subconscious mind is energized when jumping to the next line (as long as it doesn't happen too frequently). At the beginning of every new line the reader is focused, but this focus gradually wears off over the duration of the line ("Typographie", E. Ruder).