# Is there a way to break down a namespace in PHP?

Tags: php, phpcs, psr-12

I found myself looking on the internet for someone who has already answered it, but I can't find any.

I was cleaning up some code with a strict PSR12 standard, and I found this issue with namespace getting longer than the configured 80 characters (which is our soft limit, which created a warning).

So far I have found a proper way of writing readable code while staying well within the 80 lines, no matter how long the names were.  But for the namespace I haven't. Many of our namespace declarations look like this:

`namespace CompanyName\ProjectName\Domain\SubClasification\Clasification\ModuleName;`

They can get quite long, especially since many on my colleagues like very long class names, so I would like to know if there are ways to fit the namespace declaration on multiple lines?

Comment: Any line length fits as *There MUST NOT be a hard limit on line length*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a line length "soft limit" and how do I interpret this in the PSR-2 convention?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14962667/what-is-a-line-length-soft-limit-and-how-do-i-interpret-this-in-the-psr-2-conv)

Comment: Yes, fully aware of how the soft and hard limit are meant to do, but I was getting some warnings for something where I couldn't find an obvious solution to follow the guidelines provided in PSR12 while still creating clean and readable code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split the namespace on the separator character, so this is valid syntax:

```
namespace CompanyName
    \ProjectName
    \Domain
    \SubClasification
    \Clasification
    \ModuleName;
```

Alternatively, you can tell PHPCS to ignore the next line:

```
// phpcs:ignore
namespace CompanyName\ProjectName\Domain\SubClasification\Clasification\ModuleName;
```

You could also perhaps create a custom PHPCS sniff that extends the existing line length sniff but excludes namespace lines.

**[EDIT]** Note, it looks like the ability to multi-line the namespace may be going away in PHP 8: https://3v4l.org/IWbe1

Comment: Wonder if that's actually a bug in PHP 8. Sure seems like a step backwards.

Comment: Yeah dunno. It's still beta, so... <shrug>

Comment: [Bug 80041](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=80041) has been opened.

Comment: `Status: Not a bug` Oh well. :(

Comment: "and as such allow reserved keywords to appear inside them" Oooh that's cool though, I'll take that.

Comment: Had to try, oh well.

Comment: Good to see it's possible, but since this will go out with PHP8 it's probably better to solve it through PHPCS for my purpose.

Thanks though 